# How to allow external user to access SharePoint 2013 intranet?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

We have SharePoint 2013 on-premise intranet in our company and now we need to give access only for 4 external users from 2 different companies which having their own domain and network. What is the best way to give access for them apart from VPN?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to enable the Form based Authentication and create the account for those user.

1. Make Sure your DNS accessible via Internet
2. Now create a new webapplication or extend existing to configure the FBA
3. Configure the FBA.

Check this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider/

https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the "recommended" approach to allow external users is to set up Form-Based Authentication (FBA). There's multiple technical options to implement it (like adding FBA to the existing Web application, or creating an extension of the Web application).
However, for 4 users, I don't know if it's Worth it.

A simplier way is to create these for users as ActiveDirectory users in *your* Active Directory. Then publish your SharePoint through a reverse-proxy (like TMG).
One major benefit of this method is that even your internal users can now access your SharePoint from the outside. And of course, it's much more easier to implement than FBA...

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to extend the Web Application, you can have both authentication methods implemented in the same zone, and this may be desirable if you want to allow AD users to add FBA users to permissions/people lookups/etc.